# Get telerik user ID after login with facebook(Javascript)

Tags: javascript, facebook, telerik, backend

How could I access User telerik Id registered with facebook login.
I am using el.Users.currentUser() function but it returns me null object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found solution if you add master-key on your project just remove it, then you can easily get current user ID and all relative information.